# jquery text(text) security considerations

Tags: php, jquery, security

I've been setting a div equal to some user inputted data using query `$('#div').text(data)`. The security I had was to pass the data processed first on server side, returning `htmlentities(data)` etc. I noticed that when the output is displayed, the entities are not decoded. They are decoded if I use jquery `html(data)` instead.

Since it doesn't appear that the html is rendered for the data in `text(data)`, would it be okay to pass anything to it without first using `htmlentities`?

What is the proper security setup for this scenario? I read that `html(data)` was susceptible to some security holes, so that's why I was trying `text(data)` instead.

Comment: Think it this way, as long as the code are served clientside (js), you dont have to worry about it as if the client change the code, it's still only changed on his computer. Is when you send data to your server that it has to be formated to secure data.

Comment: I should clarify that this is basically a user comment. The submitted comment is displayed to everyone. What I've been finding everywhere is the security should be set when the input is displayed. I basically store it in the db using a prepared statement, but it's coming back out and needs to be processed.